# "Carry on" or "carry on for"?

Tags: grammar

I came across a sentence in a chapter named "Albert Einstein at school":

> This way you won't actually be leaving the school so if the worst comes to the worst you will be able to come back and **carry on for** your diploma.

Is "for" after "carry on" necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *for* is the start of an adverbial of purpose. "Carry on" is a phrasal verb. It is saying that 'you' will be able to carry on in order to get 'your' diploma.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are continuing your attempts to get a diploma. You are not doing anything to the actual piece of paper.